# How to eneble SSL for silverlight application calling a WCF service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ssl, silverlight-4.0

I have a an ASP.NET application hosting a silverlight 4 application that calls a WCF service.

In the web.config file of the asp.net application, i have the below configuration

```
    <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="MyBindingName">
          <binaryMessageEncoding/>
          <httpTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MyBindingName.Web.GetData">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBindingName" contract="MyBindingName.Web.GetData"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBindingName.Web.GetData">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And in the Silverligh application, the full ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file xml is below.

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Data1" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="Data1" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="Binding_GetData">
                <httpsTransport></httpsTransport>
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>

        <endpoint address="http://localhost/myApp/Webservice/Data.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Data1"
            contract="ServiceReference1.Data1" name="Data1" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/myApp/Webservice/GetData.svc"
            binding="Binding_GetData" bindingConfiguration="Binding_GetData"
            contract="GetData.GetData" name="Binding_GetData" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I now want to enable SSL for the whole application. The application should work on both https and plain http.

I have already followed the steps mentioned in the link below with out success. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi

Answer (score 0):

Is basicHttpBinding an option?

I use SSL with my SL5/WCF app, and here is how I setup my binding for SSL in my web.config. Note that I have both httpGetEnabled and httpsGetEnabled set to true.

```
<bindings>
    <binding name="SecureHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="Reporting.Web.Services.ReportingService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureHttpEndpointBinding" name="basicHttpEndpoint" contract="Reporting.Web.Services.IReportingService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

After creating my service reference, I then modified the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig in the Silverlight portion manually. Note the endpoint address!

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpEndpoint">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="../Services/ReportingService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpEndpoint"
        contract="ReportingServiceReference.IReportingService" name="basicHttpEndpoint"      />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I get the error "the mode attribute is not allowed" at <security mode="Transport">, is there any dll i have to reference first?